# seaborn 0.8+ no longer showing full x/y ticks

Tags: seaborn

Since I've upgraded to seaborn 0.8.1, I've had to make one change to my code to restore my generated charts to their original condition. The change was setting `sns.set()` after importing seaborn.

Everything looks like before except for x and y axis not displaying all labels, which was the case before the upgrade.

The following is what I am getting after the upgrade:

[image]

This is what it looked like before:

[image]

How can I restore seaborn to the xlabel tick behavior that existed before the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the call to heatmap you need to set

```
sns.heatmap(..., xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
```

The default for those arguments is `"auto"`, which would try some automatic labeling.